# Big Inventory Space for Diablo 2 Plugy

Tags: diablo-ii, diablo-ii-plugy

I'm playing Diablo 2 with Plugy Mod. I want to have a bigger inventory as it has been seen in "Project Diablo" or "Path of Diablo". Anyone knows how to keep Diablo 2 Plugy vanila but with bigger inventroy space?

**Example:**

[image]

Diablo 2 Version: 1.13c, Plugy Version: 11.02

Comment: What patch are you playing on and what version of PlugY?

Comment: @FoxMcCloud Diablo 2 Version: 1.13c, Plugy Version: 11.02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple mods for the same purpose, I've tried this one - [Diablo 2 Inventory](https://www.moddb.com/games/diablo-2/downloads/diablo-2-inventory) - and it works fine with PlugY.

Setup:

0. **Backup your stuff** - either copy the entire game and save folders to another location (just to be extra safe), or backup `data` folder in the game's root - Inventory Mod only adds files into this folder.
1. Download Inventory mod and unpack it into the game's root folder. It should add `data` folder if you don't have it yet or add some files inside it if you already have some other mods there.
2. Create a shortcut for PlugY.exe. In the shortcut's properties add `-direct -txt` to the target field, it should look like this: `D:\Games\Diablo_2\PlugY.exe -direct -txt` . This option forces game to read modified files from data folder.
3. Now you can launch the game with this new shortcut and both PlugY and Inventory mods should work together.

Here are my screenshots to proof this works:

With PlugY but without Inventory Mod:

[image]

With both mods enabled:

[image]

Comment: Very interesting. May I ask how long you played with this setup? :)

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer Unfortunately, I just tested this thing with some 1 lvl character in town. All my high level chars are from ProjectDiablo2 and are not compatible with this version. Do you want me to run some specific tests? Can't promise Horadric Cube, but I may explore Den of Evil :)

Comment: No man it's fine. I tested it myself yesterday and it works great. The only thing is that the merc gets new slots (e.g. belt) and it looks a little bitte messed up i.e. little pixel errors. Do you know if merc extra slots can be turned off?

Comment: I don't have a merc yet and cannot test, but I see that one of the mod files is data\global\ui\panel\npcinv.dc6 , could be related to merc, can you try moving / deleting it? obviously backup everything before doing this :)

Comment: I ll play around with it a little. Thanks!